# Please do bring "bad stuff" to mod attention if it doesn't look like we saw it

Tags: discussion, moderation, flagging

In some cases, SE moderation by the community is working too well...  And when content gets deleted via system auto-response to flags, or power user editing/delete activity, we the mods never actually see it.

For example, @dopplegreener and @DaleM did a good job flagging and getting the system to auto-delete a recent super offensive post (the "best mind #uck for a woman" post, I'm sure it sticks in their minds) and left a comment saying we should probably look at the account responsible.  But sadly, when that happens all the flags get auto cleaned up by the system, and I just ran across it today more than a week later by pure luck.  Same with a recent very offensive/insulting comment - site users rightfully flagged it, it got deleted, we never found out till looking at deleted comments specifically on that post when doing other stuff.

So do feel free to @mention one or more mods in those situations, or do a custom flag on a nearby undeleted item, so that we can properly follow up, when it's something that rightfully might need more vigorous addressing (I have deleted the account responsible for the former hatefulness, for example).

You don't need to ping us for everything, but if it's something that you'd have every expectation a suspension or deletion would be issued for, and it looks like maybe offensive flags or the like got to it without it otherwise coming to anyone's attention.

Thanks, and I'm logging various meta.se feature requests to help with stuff like this, but in general that's a low percentage play, so do feel free to "if you saw something, say something."

Comment: Are custom mod flags cleaned up when a question is deleted? If so we can flag it after deletion as well. Thanks for hearing us out on the mind #uck thing.

Comment: Yes, it appears they are.  Though possibly @mentioning us in comments would still have pinged us (not sure).

Comment: I think mentions are limited to people who've participated in the question, whether or not they're mods. I just sent you a mention in another comment, did you get a ping about it?

Comment: No.  Ah, SE, how you thwart us.

Comment: [Comment was here](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/6264/what-exactly-is-the-problem-player-tag-for#comment18840_6264). So, our options are: flag after the content's deleted, or flag adjacent content and say "yo check this other thing out please [link]", or ping you somewhere else where you *can* be pinged (chat, one of your posts, etc).

Comment: Looks like it.  I requested a "contact a mod" functionality on meta/se already in the past but they blew it off.

Comment: @mxyzplk, I'm guessing a "contact a mod" function might overwhelm the moderators on a really busy site.  Is that why it was turned down?

Comment: I honestly had no idea flags were "auto cleaned".  Is this true on all stackexchange sites?

Comment: Yes, best as I know.

Comment: If nothing else, you could probably flag this very meta post with a custom flag and a link (eg. for if the content was a question that was auto-vacuumed by flags)